# API 28 Location Mode is incorrect with new binary Google Accuracy Setting

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

I am currently working on an App that requires the user to have High Accuracy enabled on their device. I have the app programmed to ask and resolve this issue using an Android Popup and the Settings API.

To initially check if the user's Location mode is correct I use:

```
retVal = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE) == Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY;
```

This check seems to work on API levels 27 and below.

However with the new binary Google accuracy setting introduced in API 28, I am running into issues. If I have the accuracy turned off and turn on the accuracy setting using the popup within the app. The `Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE` will return the wrong value even though high accuracy is now enabled. The `LOCATION_MODE` returns the correct value only if the user manually changes this setting from the Settings app within Android.

I am wondering if theres a new API that accurately returns the `LOCATION_MODE` in API 28?

Answer (score 2):

According to the `Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE` [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#LOCATION_MODE):

> This constant was deprecated in API level 28.
>   To check location status, use LocationManager.isLocationEnabled(). To get the status of a location provider, use LocationManager.isProviderEnabled(String).

So I believe you can get the info you need with:

```
retVal = LocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) 
&& LocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, after trying this check , it seems to make no difference to the aforementioned problem above. 
1) Check for providers and if one of them is disabled ask user to improve accuracy.
2) User gets google pop-up to improve gps
3) User hits yes
4) accuracy is now turned on
5) OS still returns one of the providers as off so retval continues to stay false

Comment: I need retval to flip to the proper state once the user has responded to the google GPS popup. The old Flag LOCATION_MODE used to do this accurately up to API 27. However with android P unless the user does this manually from the settings app, changing the accuracy setting from within the app always returns stale GPS accuracy states from the OS including whether a provider is enabled or not.